# jquery cycle2 thumbnail scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I'm using the jquery Cycle2 plugin, and I want to create thumbnails automatically of the images in my slideshow as per this example.

```
<pre>
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
 data-cycle-slides=">div"
 data-cycle-pager-template="<span><img src='{{firstChild.src}}' /></span>"
 data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" 
 data-cycle-prev=".prev-gallery" 
 data-cycle-next=".next-gallery"
 data-cycle-pager=".cycle-pager">

<div><img src="1"></div>
<div><img src="2"></div>
<div><img src="3"></div>
<div><img src="4"></div>
<div><img src="5"></div>

<div class="cycle-pager"></div>
```

Now we can click the thumbnail in .cycle-pager span img to control the image, my question is can we make the thumbnail also as a slider with the left and right button control, so that if they there many thumnnails, we can just show several of them, and after clicking the left and right button to scroll all these thumbnails. The result seems that it has two sliders.